# Android - Crop image in both rectangle positions

Tags: android, image, android-intent, crop

I'm starting an intent for selecting and finally cropping an image by user.
Currently the intent selecting a single rectangle, but I need the square rotated by 90 degrees too. So after cropping I need two images with 200x500 and 500x200 or one image with 500x500.

My current intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("scale", false);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 500);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 200);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 500);
intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, SAVE_PATH);
```

For sample selecting a wallpaper from gallery on an Android device. There are two rectangels that will overlapped.

- [Image that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxKhg.png)!
- [Image for what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avz5C.png)!

Sorry for my bad english ;-)

Comment: Can you upload a image to tinypic or something similar and edit it into the question so we can get a better idea?

Comment: Nice idea! I have added two links to screenshots.